# Evaluating the given limit without using L'H rule.

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Evaluate $\;\lim\limits_{x\to 1} \cfrac{x^{P+1} - x(P+1) + P}{(x-1)^2} $.

The reason why I've mentioned for help in evaluating the given limit without using L'H rule is that I've already solved it using L'H rule twice (shown below) but I'm actually looking for an alter method for this question, that is without using L'H rule. Just as a curiosity to solve it in multiple ways.

Using L'H rule, this is what I've done:

$$\begin{align} & \lim_{x\to 1} \cfrac{(P+1)x^P - (P+1)}{2(x-1)} \tag{1}\\
&\lim_{x\to 1} \cfrac{P(P+1)x^{P-1}}{2} \tag{2} \\
\implies &\lim_{x\to 1} \cfrac{x^{P+1} - x(P+1) + P}{(x-1)^2}= \cfrac{P(P+1)}{2}\end{align}$$

I've used L'H rule twice here, in steps (1) and (2).

The above work was just to show what I've tried yet. I'm not sure how to move forward without using L'H rule. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $P = 0$ then result is almost obvious. If $P$ is a positive integer then it is a simple use of binomial theorem. If $P$ is negative integer then it requires more manipulation but still manageable. For general $P$ you need Taylor or L'Hospital.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set $y=x-1$, so we're dealing with
$$ \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{(1+y)^{P+1}-(1+y)(P+1)+P}{y^2} = \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{(1+y)^{P+1}-1-(P+1)y}{y^2} $$
Now, the binomial theorem says
$$ (1+y)^{P+1} = 1 + (P+1)y + \frac{P(P+1)}{2}y^2 + O(y^3), $$
and so on.

Comment: Gotcha! :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Write $X^{p+1}-(p+1)X+p=X(X^p-1)-p(X-1)$ factor $(X-1)$ so the numerator looks like $(X-1)[X^p+X^{p-1}+\cdots+X-p]$. Now look closely at the second factor and rewrite it

$$(X^p-1)+(X^{p-1}-1)+\cdots+(X-1)=(X-1)[(X^{p-1}+\cdots+1)+(X^{p-2}+\cdots+1)+\cdots+1]$$

So our limit is

$$\begin{align}\lim_{X\to 1}(X^{p-1}+\cdots+1)+(X^{p-2}+\cdots+1)+\cdots+1&=p+(p-1)+\cdots+1\\&=\frac{p(p+1)}{2}\end{align}$$

Comment: Awesome! So many ways to do a single problem. Fascinating! Thanks a lot Mr. Marwalix

Comment: Whenever we are dealing with rational fractions there is always a purely algebraic approach to cancel the indetermination

Comment: Will keep it in mind! :) Thanks a lot for your help, Marwalix!

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x) = x^{p+1} -(p+1)x.$ We are looking at

$$(1)\,\,\,\,\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}.$$

Now $f(x)-f(1) = \int_1^x (p+1)(t^p-1)\,dt.$ From the definition of the derivative of $t^p$ at $1,$ we have $t^p - 1 = p(t-1) +o((t-1)).$ Thus

$$f(x)-f(1) = \int_1^x (p+1)p(t-1)\,dt + \int_1^xo( (t-1))\,dt$$ $$ = (p+1)p(x-1)^2/2 +o((x-1)^2).$$

This shows $$(1) = (p+1)p/2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Using Taylor series built at $x=1$, you find

$$x^{P+1} - x(P+1) + P=\frac{1}{2} P (P+1) (x-1)^2+\frac{1}{6} (P-1) P (P+1) (x-1)^3+O\left((x-1)^4\right)$$ which shows, for the limit you consider not only the value but also how it is approached.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit? From where did you get $(x-1)^2$ in the last term on LHS..? I'm sure I'm missing out something ...

Comment: Because the Taylor series is built at $x=1$ so the expression is $\sum a_i (x-1)^i$. It is vasically what Chappers did.

Comment: I see, I guess I need to look at a reference for Taylor Series. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Sorry, I had typo's. It is fixed now.

Comment: Oh, got it! :) That's what I was wondering about. Everything else is clear to me now, awesome! Thanks a lot Mr. Claude for coming to my rescue.

Comment: You are very welcome !